# Retrieve values from drop down list

Tags: dropdown-attribute

I have a drop down list, which is generated by `<?php echo $this->getValuesHtml(); ?>`. Now I would like to store those values in an array. How can I do that ??

Comment: Please put more details

Comment: I am new in Magento. I am working in **select.phtml** file. I got that code there. That line is printing a drop down list. Now I would like to store those values in an array.

Comment: There is not enough information to help you with. Please add more details. My good guess is you need to add your own function ( similar to getValuesHtml ) that return you the array in stead of markup.